# Почему зацикливается функция создания/сохранения моделей?

Tags: python, django, python-2.x, python-2.7

Задача в следующем: есть 3 модели - CurrencyAccount, AccountTransaction, Emission. Нужно, чтобы при создании модели CurrencyAccount автоматически создавались другие две.

Переопределяю функцию save() в CurrencyAccount. Вот, что написал.

Сама логика состоит в следующем:

- происходит эмиссия валюты под типом identification
- пополняется счет главного юзера, админа (инициатор в данном случае будет тоже админ)
- происходит снятие со счета админа (в комментарии пишется "За прохождение идентификации пользователя (Имя Фамилия ID)")
- происходит пополнение счета пользователя (в комментарии пишется "Благодарим за прохождение идентификации!")

**модели**

```
class Emission(models.Model):
    source = models.CharField(                                           #(источник: identification / help / money / work / refferal)
        max_length=254,choices=SOURCE_CHOICES)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    initiator_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()        #(тут сохраняется айдишник пользователя, из-за которого происходит эмиссия)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2,
                               default=0.00, validators=[MinValueValidator(0.01)])  #(сумма в BLAGO)
    comment = models.TextField(default='')                 #(тут просто комментарий, пока не пустое)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.initiator_id


class AccountTransaction(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(                                             #(пополнение/расход)
        max_length=254,choices=TRANSACTION_CHOICES)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    initiator_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()        #(тут сохраняется айдишник пользователя, из-за которого происходит эмиссия)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2,
                               default=0.00, validators=[MinValueValidator(0.01)])  #(сумма в BLAGO)
    comment = models.TextField(default='')                           #(тут просто комментарий, пока не пустое)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2,
                               default=0.00, validators=[MinValueValidator(0.01)])  #(сумма в BLAGO)(для сверхи, после операции пусть сюда кешируется)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.initiator_id, self.source


class CurrencyAccount(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    userid = models.PositiveIntegerField()    #(user_id)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)     #Название
    main = models.BooleanField(default=True)     #Основной
    currency = models.ForeignKey(
        Currency, related_name='currency_of_account',
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        limit_choices_to={'enabled': True})     #Валюта
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2,
                               default=0.00, validators=[MinValueValidator(0.01)])  #(сумма в BLAGO)(для сверхи, после операции пусть сюда кешируется)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.user)
```

**в моделе CurrencyAccount**

```
def create_emission(self, currencyaccount):
    #Создаём эмиссию
        if currencyaccount.balance == 1.00:

            currencyaccount.userid = self.user.id
            print(self.user, 'asfasf')
            emission = Emission()
            emission.amount = 1.00
            emission.user = self.user
            emission.initiator_id = self.user.id
            emission.source = 'identification'
            emission.save()

    #Транзакция с зачислением BLAGO на счёт админа
            account_transaction = AccountTransaction()
            account_transaction.comment = "За прохождение идентификации пользователя {} {} {}".format(self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name, self.user.id)
            account_transaction.type = 'refill'
            account_transaction.amount = 1.00
            account_transaction.user = self.user
            account_transaction.initiator_id = self.user.id
            account_transaction.balance = 1.00
            admin = User.objects.get(id=1)
            print(admin.first_name)
            currencyaccount_admin = CurrencyAccount.objects.get(user=admin)
            print(currencyaccount_admin)
            currencyaccount_admin.balance = 1.00
            print(currencyaccount_admin.balance)
            account_transaction.save()

    #Перевод со счёта админа на счёт юзера
            account_transaction = AccountTransaction()
            currencyaccount_admin.balance = 0.00
            currencyaccount.balance = 1.00
            account_transaction.type = 'refill'
            account_transaction.amount = 1.00
            account_transaction.user = self.user
            account_transaction.initiator_id = self.user.id
            account_transaction.balance = 1.00
            account_transaction.comment = "Благодарим за прохождение идентификации!"
            account_transaction.save()
            currencyaccount.save()
            return
#
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CurrencyAccount, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        #Если юзер идентифицирован
        print(self.user.email_approval_status)
        print(self.user.first_name)
        if self.user.email_approval_status == 'done':
            print(1)
            currencyaccount = CurrencyAccount.objects.get(user=self.user)
        #Если на его счету ноль
            print(currencyaccount.balance)
            self.create_emission(currencyaccount)
```

Comment: Во-первых, что значит "зацикливается"? Во-вторых, не переопределяйте методы save, используйте сигналы.

Comment: "зацикливается" - бнсконечно обновляется страница, выводятся принты по кругу. хотя странно, ведь циклов нету в функции. мне казалось, для данного варианта подходит переопределение метода save

Comment: Цикл есть, в виде взаимной рекурсии - `save` вызывает `create_emission`, а `create_emission` вызывает `save`.

Comment: и как пофиксить предлагаете?

Comment: спасибо за подсказку. очень простое решение с помощью сигналов)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**signals.py**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def currency_account_save(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    admin = User.objects.get(id=1)
    currencyaccount_admin = CurrencyAccount.objects.get(user=admin)
    if not created:
        print(1)
        user = instance
        print(user.email_approval_status)

        if user.email_approval_status:
            print(user.email_approval_status)
            print(user.id)
            print(2)
            CurrencyAccount.objects.create(
                user = user,
                userid = user.id,
                title = 'account',
                main = True,
                currency = 'BLAGO',
                balance = 1.00,
            )
            Emission.objects.create(
                user = user,
                initiator_id = user.id,
                source = 'identification',
                amount = 1.00
            )
            AccountTransaction.objects.create(
                type = 'refill',
                user = admin,
                initiator_id = admin.id,
                amount = 1.00,
                comment = "За прохождение идентификации пользователя {} {} {}".format(user.first_name, user.last_name, user.id),
                balance = 1.00,
            )
            currencyaccount_admin.balance = 1.00
            AccountTransaction.objects.create(
                type = 'refill',
                amount = 1.00,
                user = user,
                initiator_id = user.id,
                balance = 1.00,
                comment = "Благодарим за прохождение идентификации!",
            )
            currencyaccount_admin.balance = 0.00
```